# No of days excluding weekends on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I created a team leave calendar on SharePoint and need to calculate the days of leave in a column from start date minus end date excluding weekends. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([StartDate], [EndDate],"d")), "",(DATEDIF([StartDate], [EndDate], "d")) + 1 - INT(DATEDIF([StartDate], [EndDate], "d") / 7) * 2 - IF((WEEKDAY([EndDate]) - WEEKDAY([StartDate])) < 0, 2, 0) - IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY([EndDate]) = 7, WEEKDAY([StartDate]) = 7), AND(WEEKDAY([EndDate]) = 1, WEEKDAY([StartDate]) = 1)), 1, 0) - IF(AND(WEEKDAY([StartDate]) = 1, (WEEKDAY([EndDate]) - WEEKDAY([StartDate])) > 0), 1, 0) - IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([StartDate]) = 7), WEEKDAY([EndDate]) = 7), 1, 0))
```

Also some more links:

- [Calculate days excluding weekends in SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964332/calculate-days-excluding-weekends-in-sharepoint2010)
- [Calculate date by adding days but skipping weekends](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7ea0b989-45d1-4981-a012-d4eaf4f7efb6/calculate-date-by-adding-days-but-skipping-weekends?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: does this formula calculate friday as a weekend? because if i select a 1 day leave on my tracker from 26th jan which is afriday 12am to 26th jan 11.59pm it counts it as 1 day. and if i add thursday as a leave and not friday example 25th jan it counts it as 2 days. which means in general its adding 1 day to all leaves and making it 2 and for weekends it minusing 1 which makes it left with 1.

Comment: i need it to calculate mon to fri days only and see how many days of leave a person is taken from the Start time to End Time. Please advise